# use jquery to add a div wrapper to a dynamically created drupal modual div

Tags: javascript, theming

I need to add a div with class=row around a bunch of divs that are being dynamically created by a drupal module (cant do it in the view either)

i was trying this, but since it is created dynamically, it does not work:

```
$("#row").prepend("<div id='edit-secondary-wrapper'/>");
```

this is the div that the module spits out that i want a row around

```
id='edit-secondary-wrapper'
```

Comment: Which module is used to create those elements dynamically?

Comment: shs drupal module

Comment: Are you using it with views as an exposed filter?

Comment: I did not set up the view, I am the designer trying to make it look good :) here is a screenshot of the view set up:

http://www.suzetteballew.com/bogart/ss.png

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for this

```
$("#edit-secondary-wrapper").wrap("<div class='row'></div>");
```

This wraps the div with id 'edit-secondary-wrapper' with a parent div with class 'row'.

Comment: `row = $('<div />').addClass('row'); $('#edit-secondary-wrapper').wrap(row)`  would be cleaner even :)